# Way to use $(this) to add different <p>'s on top of a set of images?

Tags: javascript

Okay the title was probably confusing but here is what i'm looking for, say I have 4 images.

```
<img src="images/first.jpg" title="something" class="group">
<img src="images/fourth.jpg" title="something2" class="group">
<img src="images/sixth.jpg" title="something3" class="group">
<img src="images/tenth.jpg" title="something4" class="group">
```

Now, when I hover over each of these images, I want a box with words in it to appear on top of the hovered image, however, depending on what the image is (first.jpg, fourth.jpg, sixth.jpg, tenth.jpg) I want the words to say different things, just the box should be the same. Any Idea on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: are you using jQuery? can you use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a tooltip, if you can use jQuery UI then look at the [tooltip widget](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: Yes I can use JQuery just as long as I know what to 'import', I 'imported' <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> already, will that do or would I need to 'import' something else as well?

Comment: you need to download jQuery as well as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and include the js as well as css files.

Comment: Hm okay I've never used JQuery before, I have a zip file called jquery-ui-these1.10.3 downloaded from http://jqueryui.com/download/all/, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to download the [jQuery file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) also

Comment: Okay, so O put <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script> in the <head> tag right? Would I be able to use tooltip now? Do I even need the jquery-ui-themes-1.10.3 zip file?

Comment: if you are ready to use the cdn version then there is no need for the zip file. you need both `jquery.js`, `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css` files

Comment: okay so <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript</script>, and then where would I get the css from?

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying & positioning a hidden DIV.

```
<img src="images/first.jpg" class="myImage" title="something" class="group">
<img src="images/second.jpg" class="myImage" title="something" class="group">
<!-- more images.. -->
<div id='imageInfo' style='display:hidden; position:absolute;'>
  Populate some details here..
  <div id='imageInfo_title'></div>
<div>

$('.myImage').hover(
    function(){ showImageInfo( $(this));},
    ('#imageInfo').hide();
);
function showImageInfo (fromImg) {
    var infoDiv = ('#imageInfo');
    infoDiv.show();
    infoDiv.position( {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        offset: "0 0",    
        of: fromImg,
        collision: "flip"
    });

    // now get some details from the <IMG>, and populate the Info Div with them.
    //    -- something like this..
    var title = fromImg.attr( 'title');
    ('#imageInfo_title').text( title);
}
```

Comment: Hm I'm kind of lost, i'm not too experienced with Javascript.  Where you wrote "Populate some details here..", suppose on the first image I want it to say "this is the first", on the second image, I want it to say "Hello, this is second", on the third image, I want it to say "Welcome".. Also, uhm what do you mean by "// now get some details from the <IMG>, and populate the Info Div with them."?

Comment: Make some progress with what you've been given, then search for further answers yourself/ or ask a separate question. Doing some of work yourself is important, to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to include jQuery is to use it from a CDN like the Google CDN

Ex

```
<html>

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($){
        $( document ).tooltip({
          track: true
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" title="one" />
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" title="two" />
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" title="Three" />
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" title="Fout" />
  </body>

</html>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tt8z4Py1YnJWlvq3eLAa)

Comment: Hm, how would I edit where I want the text to appear, I want it to appear inside the image at the bottom, and not move around as my mouse moves.

Comment: @user216485 you can change the title value to change the text also check out the [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) option to set the position of the text